# Workstation to Turtlebot PC help

Tags: ros, turtlebot, workstation, rostopic, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Right now I am on turtlebot installation part 4 network config part 5.3

On my workstation PC when I type rostopic list I get the error "unable to communicate with master" The value of ROS_MASTER_URI I get the IP of the turtlebot PC is that correct? and what do I need to do to get my workstation to communicate with my turtlebot PC

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/57682/workstation-to-turtlebot-pc-help/) by [smkybear15](https://answers.ros.org/users/4388/smkybear15/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-03-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

Yes, ROS_MASTER_URI is your turtlebot laptop ip address. You need to export ROS_HOSTNAME as well in both turtle bot laptop and your workstation laptop. i.e.

Append below statements in your .bashrc file -->

1. For Turtle bot laptop:

export ROS_MASTER_URI=:11311
export ROS_HOSTNAME=

2. For Workstation laptop:

export ROS_MASTER_URI=:11311
export ROS_HOSTNAME=

3. Now try pinging one from another.
4. Run roscore in one and do rostopic list then.
5. rostopic /echo diagnostics in another one.

It should work. Hope this helps !!

---

Originally posted by [Devasena Inupakutika](https://answers.ros.org/users/4122/devasena-inupakutika/) with karma: 320 on 2013-03-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1